# Text file: Adding a line of text only once?

Tags: java, text-files

Within my application I am adding the functionality that allows me to save details to a `txt file.`

It is working fine, however I am trying to add a header to the txt file just **once** at the **top** of the file.

The problem I am getting is that it is being generated on every second line, not just once.

**How can I change the method below to sort this problem?**

Note: header is a string declared earlier in the activity.

**Write to File method:**

```
public void writeToFileEEGPower(String data){

            boolean isHeader=true;


            Time t= new Time();
            t.setToNow();
            int timeFileMinute= t.minute;
            int timeFileDate= t.yearDay;
            int timeFileYear= t.year;

            //creating file name
            String fileName= "Maths-" +timeFileMinute + timeFileDate + timeFileYear + android.os.Build.SERIAL;

            //creating the file where the contents will be written to
            File file= new File(dir, fileName + ".txt");

            FileOutputStream os;

            try{

                boolean append= true;

                os= new FileOutputStream(file, append);

                String writeMe =data + "\n";

                if(isHeader){

                    os.write(header.getBytes());
                    isHeader=false;
                }


                os.write(writeMe.getBytes());

                os.close();
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

**particular code section of interest:**

```
if(isHeader){

                        os.write(header.getBytes());
                        isHeader=false;
                    }
```

Comment: Can you add the segment of your code where this method is being called? Also, what is header?

Comment: Declare your `isHeader` boolean outside of your `writeToFileEEGPower` method. You're only ever writing one line in that method but as `isHeader` is always declared/defined as true when you enter the method, the header text is written every time before the actual line you want to write.

Comment: if you are calling this function "writeToFileEEGPower(String data)" in a loop, it sets isHeader variable to true everytime you call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void writeToFileEEGPower(String data, boolean isHeader){
    ....
}
```

Pass in "true" for header and pass in "false" for anything after the first one?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the problem by doing as was suggested in the comments and other answer.

Basically I declared the boolean: `isHeader=true;`within the onCreate() method of the Activity and removed it's declaration from the `writeToFileEEGPower()` method.